# Using Where on association's attributes condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I have a User model which has a `languages` attribute as an array (postgres)

A `User has_many :documents` and a `document belongs_to :user`

I want to find all document that are written by users knows English and French

```
@langs = ["English", "French"]

Document.joins(:user).where(user.languages & @langs != nil )
```

This doesn't work.

What is the correct way to do this?

Schema for languages

```
t.string   "languages",              default: [],                                 array: true
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just incorrect results?

Comment: an error undefined user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document.joins(:user).where("user.languages @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", @langs)
```

This should work I tried on my models with the similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need a "contains" operation on your array in the database:

```
Document.joins(:user).where("user.languages @> ARRAY[?]", @langs)
```

Comment: this gives an error ```PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ..." ON "users"."id" = "documents"."user_id" WHERE (user.languages...```

Comment: can you post your database schema?

Comment: I added the languages part

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where('languages in (?)', @langs).map(&:documents).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: this would result in an array and not as a relation

Answer (score 0):

A complete combination with @alex's answer will be:

```
@langs = ['English', 'French']

Document.joins(:user).where('user.languages in (?)', @langs)
```

This will generate Document object(s) that match(es) with the criteria :)

Comment: this doesnt work for me.. ```PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ..." ON "users"."id" = "documents"."user_id" WHERE (user.languages...```

Comment: @NickGinanto, give the full error message. Or look to the console for the full sql query that was generated.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies on "user" or "users", "document" or "documents", "language" or  "languages"... because I tested in rails console, it's working... though I'm using MySQL not PGSQL, but should be working without problem... try 'users.languages in (?)'